# Why the orbital angular momentum equal zero for electron in s state? does it mean that the electron doesn't orbiting in s

Tags: angular-momentum, electrons, atomic-physics

Why is the orbital angular momentum $l$ equal to zero for electrons in the $s$ state? Does it mean that the electrons aren't actually orbiting?

Comment: You might find something here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109316/

Comment: It is the definition of s state.

Comment: This will help: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105703/

Comment: Electrons are not "orbiting" in the classical sense in any of the low angular momentum states, though at high angular momentum orbitals become more and more like classical orbits.

Comment: An **s** orbital can be understood as a degenerate orbit: momentum is everywhere collinear with the position vector. In classical mechanics it is a free fall with zero tangential velocity.

Answer (score 2):

I would think of it as oscillating instead of orbiting, like a quantum harmonic oscillator. Or think of it as the limit of elliptical eccentricity approaching one, with the electron passing through the nucleus, basically the way Sommerfeld did, if you want to think classically.